# Backup Plan for a VM based sharepoint website

Tags: sql-server, virtual-machine

I developed a doc sharing website for my company using Sharepoint2010 and SQLServer 2008 R2.

The website is on a virtual machine powered by Hyper-V

Now, I am thinking the disaster recovery plan.

The options I came up so far are:

1. Back up the virtual machine
2. Use CA or Stsadm backup the farm, and use sql utility to back up actual sharepoint databases

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if database server and WFE server is in same VM, you need not worry about backing up anything, all you need to do is to backup entire VM...

Comment: Just snapshot the VM.  It is quicker to get a working copy up and running again and it is simpler to backup an manage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this a production system, conventional DR processes should be followed.  No single point of failure, etc.

Backing up the VHD is good just make sure your backup destination is not the host server.    PowerShell/STSADM can be used to backup specific sites and you can create a scheduled task to launch the process.

You can snapshot as Ben and xgencoder suggested; however, there are some limitations.  See Microsoft technet [Hyper-V](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753637%28WS.10%29.aspx) articles: [Hyper-V Virtual Machine Snapshots: FAQ](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560637%28WS.10%29.aspx) and [Planning for Backup](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd252619%28WS.10%29.aspx)